# Flutter web Zoom in and out Issue

Tags: resize, zooming, flutter-web

Flutter Web APP is not resizing if i increase or decrease the zoom in size in windows OS. If simple flutter Counter app i run in chrome it doesn't resize. But in mac OS it works.

I tried using GetResponsiveView class, LayoutBuilder, Media Query but nothing works.

Comment: Did u find any solution for this?